# How to set Powershell Color scheme permanently

Tags: powershell, colors

With `PowerShell 5.0`, there are lot of customization options.
Presently I have created my own color scheme.
But I couldn't figure it out how to set these color options permanently.

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Operator -ForegroundColor "Magenta"
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Command -ForegroundColor "DarkYellow"
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Parameter -ForegroundColor "Magenta"
```

Now I kept these commands in `Profile` script, so that they will be loaded automatically, however it doesn't work in all cases when the shell is reset and if I want to load another `Profile`. Irrespective of profiles, the background color and other options which are available in `PowerShell UI` remain consistent. I want the same thing.

How do I *permanently* set these color options for `PowerShell Console`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its possible that you are setting the colour properties in the wrong profile.

PowerShell actually has 6 profiles to chose from:

**Current User, Current Host - console**:
`$Home\[My ]Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1`

**Current User, All Hosts**:`$Home\[My ]Documents\Profile.ps1`

**All Users, Current Host - console**: `$PsHome\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

**All Users, All Hosts**: `$PsHome\Profile.ps1`

**Current user, Current Host - ISE**: `$Home\[My ]Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1`

**All users, Current Host - ISE**: `$PsHome\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1`

---

Please try and set the profile colouring in the all users, all hosts profile to see if the settings persist.  If it does, then try modifying for your various profiles as a user to get the configuration you want.

for more reading on PowerShell profiles (source for this answer) - see https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/

Comment: PowerShell has four profiles, not six.  It has a different profile for *each* console host (whether this be powershell.exe, PowerGUI, ISE, VSCode, etc.)

Comment: My color profile is not to be found in any profile.ps1 file on my entire system. I type '$profile' and I'm told my profile file is C:\Users\[username]\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1. I go to the directory and the file isn't there. Also not visible when turning on display of hidden files in the folder options.

I've set a color scheme that I want to replicate everywhere. Opening PS from explorer shows me my custom color scheme. Starting PS from the task bar does not. I can't be bothered manually duplicating the color scheme.

What do?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this post now, I found my scenario a little different.

Running `$profile` in powershell displayed where my profile file should be, but there was nothing there, so I had to create the path and file referencing the output of `$profile`.

It appears the my location for the all users, all hosts profile file is at:
`C:\Users\<name>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the All Users profiles are in `C:\Windows\System32\...` which means for the 32-bit Powershell they are actually run from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\...`

Open the 64-bit PowerShell console and look at `$PROFILE.AllUsersAllHosts` then open a 32-bit PowerShell console and do the same.  You'll see the profiles are different.

You'll need to set your color schemes in all profiles for them to "take" in all conditions.
Enjoy.

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer?