# Change powershell color return error

Tags: powershell

I was trying to change the CommandForgroundColor by command

`Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Command -CommandForegroundColor DarkGray`

but I got return as:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CommandForegroundColor'

Also, [How to set Powershell Color scheme permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/1037413/how-to-set-powershell-color-scheme-permanently)?

Comment: Are you sure there actually is a property called `CommandForgroundColor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct parameter is "**-ForegroundColor**"

Test code example:

```
PS > [enum]::GetValues([System.ConsoleColor]) | Foreach-Object {Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor $_}      

DarkGray
```

Comment: How can I make it 'forever' change?

Comment: Since that stuff is used per-session, you will have to make a profile file to apply the settings whenever you launch PowerShell. Basic info on that here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff461033.aspx